# Windows TempDirectory in Subdirectory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, temporary-files

I have a file that writes constantly to my TempDirectory.
I have set the TempDirectory to *C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp*
but my files are written to *C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp* **\3**

Why does Windows change the TempDirectory ?
I am using a Windows Server 2008 R2
I am Admin on this Server

If I go to the CMD and type %temp% it prints the **\3** directory

Answer (score 0):

[Tmp Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEds.png)

Check the variables on the picture in the link above on your system if some of them points to C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp\3 then you will need to change it to point to C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: As said above, quote: "I have set the TempDirectory to C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp" which I have done via the Environment Variables. Sadly this isn't the problem

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @Bongo To answer your original question:
 I don't believe that the windows itself is changing the variable. There are two TEMP variables actually one for your current user and one system variable 

The one that you were setting is for your user only the other one can be found in the list of System variables below

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but I stumbled upon this and the explanation is found over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521277/why-does-temp-resolve-to-a-non-deterministic-path-of-the-form-temp-digit

The gist is

> multiple terminal services sessions for the same user don't (by default) share a temp directory.

This is a server edition issue.

Original answer is quoted from /u/Damien_The_Unbeliever:

> The problem lay in the [Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Temporary folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759190%28WS.10%29.aspx) group policy. If you don't select **Do not use temporary folders per session**, then these TEMP subdirectories are created. There is also [a knowledge base article describing the registry keys behind these group policies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243215).

Personally, I find the first comment in reply to be the most useful:

> Why does it matter if the temp location jumps around anyway, it's temporary!

### See also

- [Use separate temporary folders for each session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759190%28WS.10%29.aspx)